# MonoDevelop.CsharpBinding Reference Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, steambot

Trying to compile this project (https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) and everything else seems fine except for the fact that I can't install this particular reference.

> The referenced component 'MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding' could not be found.

Followed the instructions provided on the WIKI including:

"After Nuget install, restart VS. After the restart, try to build the solution. If it doesn't work, go to Tools -> Options -> Package Manager -> Then tick on Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build. Retry to build the solution, and it should work."

Any ideas?

Error:
http://postimg.org/image/ulcgga2h7/

Edit: I also wanted to add that there are people going around down voting all the questions with steam bot tag associated with them. Remember this is a place to ask questions for all types of programmers, beginning to advanced.

Comment: You should insert the message of the error, not a screenshot

Comment: The referenced component 'MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding' could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a warning, not an error.  If you're compiling from Visual Studio, the Mono Develop bindings won't be there for obvious reasons *(you're not using Mono Develop)*.  However, the project still compiles and runs fine.

Comment: It actually won't compile though. I think the project does use Mono Develop bindings for some resources. Is there a way to manually install them on Visual Studio 2012 or 2010? If you look at the screen shot I posted in the initial question you can see further errors.